# Let $E$ be a Banach space, $F=\mathcal{l}^1$, and let $T\in\mathcal{L}(E,F)$ be surjective, prove that $T$ has a right inverse

Tags: functional-analysis

this is an exercise from Brezis Book, 2.11. My attempt:
T is surjective so thanks to the open mapping theorem, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists  $x_n\in E$ such that $\|x_n\|\leq c$ ($c$ is the constant from the open mapping theorem) and  $T(x_n)=e_n$, where $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is the canonical basis of $\mathcal{l}^1$, and define the next function:
$S:\mathcal{l}^1\rightarrow E$ where if $y=(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\mathcal{l}^1$ then $$S(y)= \displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n(x_n)}.$$
This "function" is  near to be the right inverse of $T$ because $T\circ S=Id$, $S(y)$ is a convergent serie for every $y\in\mathcal{l}^1$ and $S$ is linear and bounded but I can't  prove that is well defined, I mean, we don't know if $T$ is injective and maybe could exists an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $e_n=T(x_1)=T(x_2)$ with $x_1\neq x_2$ so the definition of $S$ is ambiguous. Please could you explain me what is happening?

Comment: The right inverse need not be unique, which is what you explain.  But by "choosing" those vectors $x_n$ your formula produces a right inverse.  Perhaps only one among many right inverses.  You choose $x_n$ so that $T(x_n) = e_n$.  Since $T$ is a function, and $e_1 \ne e_2$ we get $x_1 \ne x_2$.  This is "$T$ is a function", and does not require "$T$ is injective".

Answer (score 1):

Let $T_n(y)=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}y_nx_n$, $T_n$ is continuous and $\|T_n(y)\|\leq \|y\|c$.

We have $lim_nT_n(x)$ exists since $T_n(x)$ is a Cauchy sequence, the uniform bounded principle implies that there existsa bounded operator $T$ such that $T(x)=lim_nT_n(x)$.
See the corrolaries

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle